# Commissioning never completes

Tags: server, maas

Sometimes a node will boot to a login prompt but the maas server says the node is still "commissioning".

Answer (score 4):

This can happen when the clock on the node is too far out of sync for the OAuth verification to work, which results in the node timing out when trying to download from the metadata service and eventually continues booting to a login prompt without finishing the commissioning script.

Try checking the clock on the node and reset it if it's very different from the MAAS server's clock.

Another problem can be `/etc/maas/maas_local_settings.py` having the wrong `DEFAULT_MAAS_URL`.